# Open and close windows with closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I want to open and close a window on click of two buttons.
Open button opens and close button closes the window. Simple !

I achieved this by help of two separate functions. You guys guessed it. One for open and other for close.

***However, this involves making `myWindow` object global. To avoid this I am thinking if closures can come in handy to scope the `myWindow` object to a function defined manually.***

I tried doing something like the code pasted below but not sure how to get it working. Right now `publicClose` is undefined.

*Again, my emphasis is to avoid any global declaration.*

```
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Day 5-6</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="buttons">
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="openWindow()">Open Window</button></li>
        <li><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="publicClose()">Close Window</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">


    function openWindow(){
        var myWindow = windowCenter("", "", 400, 200 );

        function windowCenter(url, title, w, h) {
        // Fixes dual-screen position                         Most browsers      Firefox
            var ScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
            var ScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

            width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
            height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

            var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + ScreenLeft;
            var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + ScreenTop;
            var myWindow = window.open("", "", 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
            myWindow.document.write("<strong>I am child window.</strong>")
            // Puts focus on the newWindow
            if (window.focus) {
                myWindow.focus();
            }
        }
        function closeWindow(){
            myWindow.close();
            
        }
        var publicClose = {
            close: closeWindow;
        }

        return publicClose;

        
    }

    


  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes a working copy

```
<title>Day 5-6</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var closeWindow;  
  function openWindow() {
    var myWindow;
    windowCenter("", "", 400, 200);

    function windowCenter(url, title, w, h) {
      // Fixes dual-screen position                         Most browsers      Firefox
      var ScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
      var ScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;

      var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
      var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

      var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + ScreenLeft;
      var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + ScreenTop;
      myWindow = window.open("", "", 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
      myWindow.document.write("<strong>I am child window.</strong>");
        // Puts focus on the newWindow
      if (window.focus) {
        myWindow.focus();
      }
    }

    closeWindow = function() {
      myWindow.close();
    }

  }

  function publicClose() {
      closeWindow();
  }

</script>

<body>
  <div class="buttons">
    <ul class="list-inline">
      <li>
        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="return openWindow();">Open Window</button>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="publicClose()">Close Window</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


</body>
```

what are the changes ?
instead of return an object, i assign close window to a global variable, which creates a clousure of `openWindow` function.

inside `windowCenter` function, `myWindow` is not a new variable, instead its the variable from `openWindow` context. and i dont return anything from `windowCenter` function

removed `publicClose` from `openWindow` context, and added a `publicClose` function in global context. but that can be avoided and directly `closeWindow` can be called from the button click

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `publicClose` global, you have to define it global ;-)

```
var publicClose = {};

function openWindow(){
    // --- your code from above here ---

    publicClose = {
        close: closeWindow;
    }
}
```

Also, the your close function call is wrong. Fixed:

```
    <li><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="publicClose.close()">Close Window</button></li>
```